# Refreshing screen in Xamarin Live Player

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-live-player

Is there a way to refresh the screen in the app on Xamarin Live Player without stopping and restarting debug mode?

If I make a change in my xaml file, I currently need to stop debug mode and restart it which is not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try LiveXAML, it works great! Check out https://www.livexaml.com/

EDIT: It works on physical devices, not just on emulations.